# Is $(0,2)\cup(2,3)$ dense in$ [0,3]$?

Tags: metric-spaces

I think $(0,2)\cup(2,3)$ is dense in [0,3] since the only problem point would be 2

but $B(2,r)\cup [0,3]$ is non-empty for all $r>0$

is this ok?

Comment: That union should be an intersection, but otherwise yes that's the right idea; although you also need to do the same argument for the endpoints $0$ and $3$.

Comment: I think that the union in the second line should be an "intersection" (\cap instead of \cup).

Comment: Right, but why is $2$ any more of a problem point that $0$ or $3$? If the question were "is $(0,2)$ dense in $[0,2]$?" would you say "no worries with $0,$ the only problem point is $2$"?

Comment: @bof: my thinking was that my set is basically the same without the number 2 in the middle or the end points.  so was worried there might be some interval around 2 where the intersection maybe empty as 2 was  not in my set.         . the endpoints I figured didn't need checking as any ball around a point near 0 or 3 would clearly intersect with [0,3]

Comment: jiboom, it is equally clear that $B(a,r)$ intersects $(0,2)\cup(2,3)$ for all $a = 0,2,3$. You considering one thing clear and the other not is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the closure of $(0,2)\cup (2,3)$ in $[0,3]$?